# Checking whether a certain type is an Action delegate

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I'm trying to check whether a given type is an action delegate, regardless of the amount of parameters.

The following code is the only way I know how to do this.

```
    public static bool IsActionDelegate( this Type source )
    {
        return source == typeof( Action ) ||
               source.IsOfGenericType( typeof( Action<> ) ) ||
               source.IsOfGenericType( typeof( Action<,> ) ) ||
               ....
               source.IsOfGenericType( typeof( Action<,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,> ) );
    }
```

`IsOfGenericType()` is another extension method of mine, which does what it says, it checks whether the type is of the given generic type.

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are just after the delegates that have a void return type you could do the following:

```
public static bool IsActionDelegate(Type sourceType)
{
    if(sourceType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MulticastDelegate)) && 
       sourceType.GetMethod("Invoke").ReturnType == typeof(void))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

This would not distinguish between `Action` and `MethodInvoker` (or other void delegates for that matter) though. As other answers suggest you could examine the type name, but that kinda smells ;-)
It would help if you could clarify for what reason you want to identify `Action` delegates, to see which approach would work best.

Comment: I dunno if searching by name is all that bad given that the name comes from a library namespace and not user code.

Comment: Great insight, thanks! I'm trying to make a generic Delegate.CreateDelegate method. E.g. `CreateDelegate<Action<object>>( owner, method );` It's a work in progress so I don't know yet whether it will be possible. But that's why I need to analyze the generic parameter and check what type of delegate is expected.

Comment: @Ritch - it reminds me of checking the browser type in javascript instead of feature checking - the later is much cleaner. Maybe unwarranted in this case, but I wouldn't touch the name if I didn't absolutely have to.

Answer (score 4):

```
    static Type[] _actionTypes = new[]{
        typeof(Action),
        typeof(Action<>),
        typeof(Action<,>),
        typeof(Action<,,>),
        typeof(Action<,,,>),
        typeof(Action<,,,,>),
        typeof(Action<,,,,,>),
        typeof(Action<,,,,,,>),
        typeof(Action<,,,,,,,>),
        typeof(Action<,,,,,,,,>),
        typeof(Action<,,,,,,,,,>),
        typeof(Action<,,,,,,,,,,>),
        typeof(Action<,,,,,,,,,,,>),
        typeof(Action<,,,,,,,,,,,,>),
        typeof(Action<,,,,,,,,,,,,,>),
        typeof(Action<,,,,,,,,,,,,,,>),
        typeof(Action<,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,>)
    };
    private static bool IsAction(Delegate d)
    {
        return d != null && Array.IndexOf(_actionTypes, d.GetType()) != -1;
    }
```

Comment: Technically the code should be Array.IndexOf(_actionTypes, d.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition())!=-1.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
    private static bool IsActionDelegate(this Type source)
    {
        var type = source.Name;
        return source.Name.StartsWith("System.Action");
    }
```

Example:

```
public static class Test
{
    public static bool IsActionDelegate(this Type source)
    {
        var type = source.Name;
        return source.Name.StartsWith("Action");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action<string> one = s => { return; };
        Action<int, string> two = (i, s) => { return; };
        Func<int, string> function = (i) => { return null; };

        var single = one.GetType().IsActionDelegate();
        var dueces = two.GetType().IsActionDelegate();
        var func = function.GetType().IsActionDelegate();
    }
}
```

Single and dueces are true. func is false

Comment: I thought of checking the name before, but was hoping there was a cleaner/safer solution.

Comment: Yea, it seemed obvious. I was just curious about it which is why I wrote it. I don't think there's anything safe when you are mucking with independent types and treating them as equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

These are distinct types with nothing in common but their name.  The only semi-reasonable shortcut I can think of:

```
public static bool IsActionDelegate( this Type source )
{
    return source.FullName.StartsWith("System.Action");
}
```

Certainly not fail-safe, but whomever declares his own types in the System namespace deserves some pain and suffering.